# Find the name that was associated to a value of an OptionSet

Tags: swift, optionsettype

So I have an `OptionSet`:

```
struct Ability: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let create  = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let read    = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let update  = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let delete  = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 3)

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
}
```

I'm just writing one as an example here. In reality my code doesn't know what `OptionSet` it has exactly, it only knows it gets an `OptionSet`. What I want to do is be able to get the name of the option from its `rawValue` as a `String`.

So basically I want to write a function with the following signature:

```
func convertOptionToString<OS: OptionSet>(optionSet: OS) -> String
```

Where `convertOptionToString(Ability.read)` would return `"read"`

Of course I know that `OptionSet`s can also hold multiple values, but I already know how I would deal with that situation, so that's not a problem I need help with.

I am hoping that this problem can be solved using some kind of smart Reflection, but I haven't been able to find out how yet. Anybody want to give it a go?

Answer (score 3):

Update your `struct` to conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement the `description` property:

```
struct Ability: OptionSet, CustomStringConvertible {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let create  = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let read    = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let update  = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let delete  = Ability(rawValue: 1 << 3)

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    var description: String {
        var vals = [String]()
        if self.contains(.create) {
            vals.append("create")
        }
        if self.contains(.read) {
            vals.append("read")
        }
        if self.contains(.update) {
            vals.append("update")
        }
        if self.contains(.delete) {
            vals.append("delete")
        }

        return vals.joined(separator: ",")
    }
}

print(Ability.read)
let opts: Ability = [ .read, .delete ]
print(opts)
```

Output:

> read
>   read,delete

Comment: This is nice. Is there any way to just extend `OptionSet`?

Comment: @Honey Sure, you can leave `Ability` is-as and then create `extension Ability: CustomStringConvertible {` and put `description` in the extension.

Comment: I meant an extension on `OptionSet` not on `Ability`

Comment: @Honey I don't believe so. From `OptionSet` there is no way to know the list of possible values for a given `OptionSet` and their corresponding names.

Comment: This is why I was hoping it could be done using reflection. I would prefer to not obligate the consumers of my code to write a description variable. Because that is just super tedious to write.